# Multi Effect device with tube

Tags: electric-guitar, guitar-effects

I have used a VOX Tonelab LE for almost ten years, and it starts to fall apart. Therefore I'm looking for a replacement. In my view, VOX used to stand out among modelling amps by adding a tube, thus creating very good distortion sounds. My question is whether there is anything comparable nowadays in terms of

- flexibility, i.e. all common effects (chorus, flanger, delay, reverb, phaser, ...) are on boad
- high quality amp models

I also need a fairly "large" board with several foot switches and an expression pedal.

I realize that modelling technique has improved in the meantime, so can I expect all this (in particular nice distortions) from Line 6/Boss/... pedals that do not have an integrated tube?

Comment: I recently sold my old Tonelab. The newer stuff sounds better because it’s all digital either way and the tube was really just a gimmick. Check out the new modeling devices at a store if you can. Unfortunately, this question is off topic here because we don’t do gear recommendations. Just let go of the tube idea and go through a more open minded product selection process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is not the latest model, the Zoom G5 (not the G5n) is a great choice and it includes an actual 12AX7 tube to add color to the sound.  In addition, it is incredibly easy to use and allows you to adds up to 9 effects in any order, and you can even have the same effect more than once in your effects chain.  And it is affordable.  Good luck.  :-)

Comment: Hi Carl - while you have obviously helped, we ask that people don't answer obviously off topic questions, as it encourages more.